# Replace cells having inf value by 1

Tags: matlab

Given the following

Columns 1 through 17

```
    0.3108    0.7273       Inf    0.2878   -0.0947    0.1286   -0.3108    0.5634    0.2822    0.2362   -0.2628    0.0960   -0.1675   -0.0934   -0.1710   -0.3077   -0.2726

Columns 18 through 20

   -0.0630   -0.5097    0.1823
```

How to replace inf values by 1.
I know how to do it using a loop but is there a way to do it without?

What if want to save it with another name?i.e. data remains same data1=data except inf is replaced by 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [isinf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/isinf.html) to detect Inf, and use the output as a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing) into your array:

```
data(isinf(data)) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Richante. What if want to save it with another name?i.e. data remains same data1=data except inf is replaced by 1?

Comment: `new_data = data; new_data(isinf(new_data)) = 1;`